# Javascript querySelctorAll() Display Collection

Tags: javascript, html

Have a question about querySelectorAll(). Is there a cleaner way of displaying each index?

```
<form id="records">
    <label class="collect" for="lineOne">Line One</label>
    <input class="collect" name="lineOne" type="text">
    <br>
    <label class="collect" for="lineTwo">Line Two</label>
    <select class="collect" name="lineTwo">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit">
    <button type="button" onclick="newRecord()">New Record</button>
</form>
```

I would like to loop through these and display:

```
function newRecord() {
    let frm = document.getElementById('records');
    let collect = document.querySelectorAll('.collect');
    for (let i = 0; i < collect.length; i++) {
        frm.appendChild(collect[i]);
    }
}
```

In my console I can see the "array-like" collection, it's exactly what I need. But I cannot get it to echo (if you will) onto the page. I've tried `createElement` in my loop as well. Console says there are unexpected characters (which I understand what it's saying).

I do have it working, but I'm having to collect each part separately and piece it together, like `collect[i].getAttibute('...')`, `document.creatElement('collect[i].tagName')` using `if` `else if` with tag names as conditions such as `=== 'SELECT'`, `=== 'INPUT'`, `=== 'LABEL'` etc.

There's got to be a cleaner, easier way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: you are just moving elements inside the form, why ?

Comment: I think @yainspan may have answered my question. No, I am not trying to move elements in my form. I'm trying to "clone" them to add a new record to insert into a database. So instead of submitting one record at a time, I can add records as needed in the form.